# Printing 2 Objects in Python

Tags: python, object, printing

This is my code I am trying to get the two objects to print and I cannot. Looking for help. I am trying to get the output to print like this for an example.
Cat         0.  Cat         1.  Cat

Dog         1.  Dog         2.  Dog

Horse       2.  Horse       3.  Horse

Below is my code.

```
#object 1 is car 
class vechicle:

    car=0
    color="Blue"
    model="Ford"
    size="4 Door"

#properties

def __init__(self, model, color, size):
 
    self.model = model
    self.car = 0
    self.color = color
    self.size = size
    
def cars_sold(self):
    self.car = self.car+1
    return self.car

def see_color(self):
    return self.color

def size(self):
    return self.size

def model(self):
    return self.model

def set_color(self, new_color= 'Blue'):
    self.color = new_color

#object 2


class shoe:
    
#creating a list
    
    list=[]
    list_name = "Shoes"
    list_decription = "Records of types of shoes"
    list_owner = "Vans"

 #properties   
    
    def __init__(self, name, description, owner):
        self.list_name = name
        self.list_description = decription
        self.list_owner = owner
        
        def item(self,item):
            self.list.append(item)
            
        def length(self):
            return len(self.list)
        
        def decription(self):
            return self.list_decription
        def owner(self):
            return self.list_owner
        def change_owner(self, new):
            self.list_owner = new
            
#sending the values

    def printing(self,index = None):
        if index==0:
            i=0
            while i < len(self.list):
                print(i+1,".",self.list[i])
                i = i +1
            if index ==1:
                    i=0
                    while i<len(self.list):
                        print(self.list[i])
                        i=i+1
                        print(object)
```

I do not have any errors but there no output so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Where in the code did you call the printing function ?

Comment: I guess I didn't. How can I incorporate that in my code?

Answer (score -1):

Since there is only one function in your code that deals with printing, I am going to assume based on the question title that this is the part that you are asking about.

To make the output look the way you have formated replace your `printing` method with this...

```
    def printing(self):
        for i, out in enumerate(self.list):
            if i < len(self.list) - 1:
                out = out + f" {i+1}."
            print(out, end=" ")
```

or as a function:

```
def printing(data):
    for i, out in enumerate(data):
        if i < len(data) - 1:
            out = out + f" {i+1}."
        print(out, end=" ")
```

In practice would work like this

```
lst = ["Dog", "Dog", "Horse", "Horse"]
printing(lst)
```

output:

```
Dog 1. Dog 2. Horse 3. Horse
```